# How can i do this calculation in c#

Tags: c#, linq, parsing, math, timespan

Ok, so right now I have a `TasksGroup` object which has a Taches  list. This Taches list contains many Tasks that has properties called `TaskDBA` and `TaskDuration` which are needed for the calculation.

But I am stuck for the `TaskDBA` exponent part and don't know how to proceed. Thanks for help!

**The Formula:**

> 10 x Log [  SUM( TaskDuration x 10^(0.1 x TaskDBA) +...+ TaskDuration2 x
> 10^(0.1 x TaskDBA2)+....]

`TaskDuration` is a string and `TaskDBA` is an int

The duration is initially taken from an entry box in the format HH:MM:SS so what I do here is that I have the method `GetDuration` that converts a duration to a `TimeSpan` object.

```
private TimeSpan GetDuration(string duration)
{
    var value = duration.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
    var datetime = new TimeSpan(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
    return datetime;
}
```

**The calculation method I am stuck at is**

> 10^(0.1 * TaskDBA)

Taches = list of Tasks

```
public double CalculateExposition(TasksGroup group)
{
    // i thought this could be usefull
    var GetDBA = group.Taches.Select(x => (double)(x.TaskDBA));

    //i first use x.TotalHours because i need my TimeSpan to be converted to decimal

    var sum = group.Taches.Select(x => GetDuration(x.TaskDuration)).Sum(x => x.TotalHours * 
    Math.Pow(10,GetDBA.));

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You could replace `GetDuration` with a call to `TimeSpan.ParseExact`. And for that inner `Sum`, use something different than `x` so it's not confusing with the Select's `x`. There's no need to cast `TaskDBA` to double. For `0.1 x TaskDBA` I would just do `TaskDBA / 10.0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to simplify your method like this:

```
public double CalculateExposition(TasksGroup group)
{
    return 10 * Math.Log(group.Taches.Sum(x => TimeSpan.Parse(x.TaskDuration).TotalHours * Math.Pow(10, x.TaskDBA / 10.0)));
}
```

You don't need to do any `Select`, just directly do the sum you need. As you can see, for each `Tach`, all you need to do is:

```
TimeSpan.Parse(x.TaskDuration).TotalHours * Math.Pow(10, x.TaskDBA / 10.0)
```

---

### ** Update **

As the hours in the input string can be greater than 23 and `TimeSpan.Parse` and `ParseExact` don't support that, this is what you need to to:

```
private TimeSpan GetDuration(string duration)
{
    var parts = duration.Split(':').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
    return new TimeSpan(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);
}

public double CalculateExposition(TasksGroup group)
{
    return 10 * Math.Log(group.Taches.Sum(x =>
        GetDuration(x.TaskDuration).TotalHours * Math.Pow(10, x.TaskDBA / 10.0)
    ));
}
```

Comment: idk if you're still here but maybe should could shine the light let's say the user enters 03:03:03, there will be no problem, BUT if he enters 33:33:33 i get : Unhandled exception : System.OverflowException: The TimeSpan could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits. any idea why ? Thanks !

Comment: oh i guess you can't go above 24 hours

Comment: Yes, you can, but then you need to use a different approach. Let me update.